# How do I automate the installation of Oracle Client on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, oracleclient

I have servers running Windows Server 2019 that all need the most recent Oracle Client to be installed on them. It's pretty easy to install Oracle Client interactively, but I've thus far been unable to trick it into a completely hands-off installation from Powershell scripts.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Networking & Servers is not in my skillset but I'm wondering if you know about other Stack Exchange sites, which include both subjects, and which might be able to help >>> https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: You want to use a package manager for this. Have a look at: https://chocolatey.org/. If the oracle client installer offers a silent install parameter you can package it, put it in your own local repository and roll it out to your servers with PowerShell.

Comment: Could you solve it? Oracle offers the usage of "Response files", but I don't understand them in detail ...

Comment: choco doesnt have one for Oracle client for apps. I found [this link](https://qtechbabble.wordpress.com/2020/09/23/silently-install-oracle-client-18c/#:~:text=setup.exe%20-silent%20-nowait%20-ignoreSysPrereqs%20-ignorePrereqFailure,-waitForCompletion%20-force%20%22ORACLE_BASE%3DC%3Aapp%5B%26client%26%5D%22%20%22ORACLE_HOME%3DC%3Aapp%5B%26client%26%5Dproduct18.0.0client32%22%20%22oracle.install.IsBuiltInAccount%3Dtrue%22%20%22oracle.install.client.installType%3DRuntime%22) but not sure how far it may be helfpul.